# Working of Views module in Drupal 7

Tags: views

I am very new to Drupal. I would like to know how Views module work.
I need clarification on my following understanding about the use of Views module,

"Views are not for creating new content or inputting data, I need to create content with page/article/field collection etc. then I have to provide views module to display those contents using views module."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to become familiar with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (cfr. your "*know how Views module works*"), checkout the (free) [set of 30 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/taming-the-beast-learn-views) about the Views module. These tutorials elaborate on all sorts of Views related topics, such as:

- Basic settings, fields, sorting.
- Contextual filters.
- Relationships.
- Grouping fields, rewriting fields.
- Other modules typically used in conjunction with Views.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple,
Content types, Feeds, Webforms are like data input.
Views is like data output.

- Views are specifically used to display the content nodes, feeds, etc. in various formats and can generate reports and exports. But You may also embed views in content types for example to keep track of previous data while entering new data.
- Content types are used to input the data and we may also use feeds to import bulk data from csv or other file formats.